# Really Red rash looking swollen nipples

Tags: dogs, health, diseases, reproduction

My female Pitt just had puppies and she has a really bad I don't even know what it is a rash or I don't know but it's all over her stomach and nipples and her nipples are really swollen bad um I don't know if the puppies should be nursing off her I went and got them puppies formula but they really stink and I don't know what to do about my female to help her and or if the puppies are gonna be okay cause they have been nursing off her there like a week and a half

Comment: she may develop mastitis if you take the pups off her. Nursing is the best. It's impossible to diagnose without pictures. Taking her to the vet would be the best option. Ensure she has plenty of calcium in her diet as a deficiency can cause problems for nursing dogs.